# /v2/ is soon shutting down - but /rest/ gives 404

Tags: api, oauth, linkedin-api

**Edit**: I updated the way I extract user data, so let's streamline the question:

I use the Oauth / OpenId Connect solution to sign in users, and get their data by calling /v2/userinfo.
But recently I got an email saying that all /v2/xxxx endpoints will be shut down 30 June, and that we should call /rest/xxxx instead.

But when I call /rest/userinfo I get a 404.
A few endpoints seem to exist at /rest/ but most I've tried don't.

The info about the shutdown of /v2/ can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/versioning

---

**Original**: I'm using the LinkedIn Oauth solution for sign ins, and getting user data.

So I call
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization
and
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken to get an access token.

Then I can collect basic user information by calling
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me
and then ge the email address by calling
[https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle%7E)))

But recently got an email from LinkedIn that their /v2/ API will be shut down in a month. So we need no migrate to the /rest/ versioned api instead.

Changing /v2/me to https://api.linkedin.com/rest/me works fine.
But [https://api.linkedin.com/rest/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))](https://api.linkedin.com/rest/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle%7E))) gives a 404

Is there some other way to retrieve the users email address, that I don't know about?
Or is it just some of the /v2/ endpoints that will be shut down, so /v2/emailAddress endpoint will continue working?

Comment: I also need help with this

Comment: I rewrote the process somewhat, according to this guide
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin-v2
(Activated the "Sign In with LinkedIn v2" addon, request "openid profile email" in scope - and then i call /v2/userinfo instead of /v2/me).

That way I actually get the email address and so on.
But there's a catch. /rest/userinfo returns a 404. So the problem remains. If they shut down all v2 endpoints, then even the "new" OpenID Connect  process fails.

Comment: What do you think will be the permanent solution?

Answer (score 2):

The Marketing APIs are the ones that must be versioned and will use the /rest/ path. To my knowledge, other APIs aren't changing. The /userInfo endpoint is a Consumer API endpoint so you should be able to continue using /v2/ with that.